# Neither my grub and my bios open, what do i do?

Tags: bios

I'm currently using linux mint 20.1 and when I try to get to the bios the screen just goes black. I also can't get to grub. I tried to edit some grub files but it didn't work. I need to access the bios to boot from an usb drive. Any ideas?

Comment: Try to disconnect any hard drive and usb disks you have to see if you the bios screen still goes black. A black screen is not how it should works, also make sure that you used the right key to access the BIOS. What's your motherboard or PC ? Also, if you get to the BIOS, try to set a bigger timer for POST so you can chose your boot device.

Comment: Make sure UEFI fast boot is off. UEFI fast boot, skips the old BIOS Power-on self-test (POST), assumes no changes to system. Power shutdown and then "cold" boot normally allows for access to boot keys as then it does the scan of hardware.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the monitor... I switched it and now the bios appears